# VideoJS m3u8 stream with multiple audio tracks doesn’t play on iOS devices

Tags: html, video.js

I have a web app that I’ve created that uses videojs to play m3u8 files created with ffmpeg.

Any file that has a single or no audio works fine, but I have some files that have 9 audio tracks that lets the user select the track they want to listen to. This works fine on desktop but gives an error saying no comparable source could be found when viewing on iOS.

I have tried the overridenative argument but that doesn’t work.

```js
‘’’
var overrideNative = false;
var player = document.querySelector("#my-video");

  player = videojs('my-video', {
    playbackRates: [-2, -1, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 2],
    fluid: true,
    aspectRatio: "16:9",
    liveui: true,
    controls: true,
    preload: "auto",
    poster: "",
    html5: {
      vhs: {
        overrideNative: overrideNative
      },
      nativeVideoTracks: !overrideNative,
      nativeAudioTracks: !overrideNative,
      nativeTextTracks: !overrideNative
    }
    });
‘’’
```